# Why spam questions are not removed from the recently changed lists once deleted?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Clicking on `x questions with new activity` banner to see latest activity I often also see "old" (> 5 min:) ) spam questions still in the list, however the question itself is already removed.

Why their title isn't removed from the list?

[image]

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/